# Center content based on max-width of it's children?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm not sure this is possible to do with CSS, but I want to double check. I have a responsive table that can have anywhere from 3 to 10 columns. The columns are broken into three sections. The column on the left has 30% width, a max-width of 500px, and a min-width of 190px.

The middle container is where most of the columns live. It can have anywhere from 1 - 8 columns. The container has a width of 60%. Each column inside that container has a width divided by the amount of columns in that container. e.g. If there are three columns then each column gets 33.33% width. These columns also have a min-width of 100px and a max-width of 250px.

The last column has a width of 10% and the same min-width and max-width of the columns in the middle 100px and 250px.

I would like the table to be able to stretch based on the max-width of the children elements. So for instance if the window's width is expanded to 2560px and there are 5 columns the width of the table will be 1500px (500 + 250*4). Likewise if there are 9 columns then the table will be 2500px (500 + 250*8).

And of course, if the window was made smaller than each column would shrink until it hit it's min-width. Is there a way to do this with just CSS?

Comment: Would be helpful to get the actual code instead of the code's story.

Comment: Yes it would, but when I put my code in Codepen it doesn't look right so I thought explaining my problem would be better.